# How to check if jsonjavaobject is already part of an array?

Tags: arrays, json, xpages-ssjs

I am building a simple array of jsonobjects via:

```
var jsonObjArr = sessionScope.get("tmpAssessors");

var jsonObj:com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject = new com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonJavaObject();

var area = getComponent("inpArea").value;
var person = getComponent("personField").value;

jsonObj.putJsonProperty("area", area);
jsonObj.putJsonProperty("person", person);

jsonObjArr.push(jsonObj);

sessionScope.put("tmpAssessors",jsonObjArr);
```

However I would like to check if a similar jsonobject (same key-pair values) is already in the array so I will not push it in a second time.

How can I check this?

Comment: for now I compare the objects by converting them to strings and compare them as strings :-?

Comment: If jsonObjArr were a JsonJavaArray, you could have used jsonObjArr.contains(jsonObj).

Answer (score 0):

Provided that **JsonJavaObject.equals** performs a correct equality check, your code should work if you replace `jsonObjArr.push(jsonObj);` with the following:

```
var _doesArrayContainElement=function(a,e){
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if (a[i].equals(e)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

if (!_doesArrayContainElement(jsonObjArr,jsonObj)) jsonObjArr.push(jsonObj);
```